# Dropdown is coming behind carousel

Tags: javascript, css

I have set z index in every place, but it did nothing.

I want the dropdown to appear outside the carousel, as shown here:

I have set z index in every place, but it did nothing.

I want the dropdown to appear outside the carousel, as shown here

```js
<script>  
$( ".choose_nav_landing" ).click(function() {
 $('.choose-list').slideToggle(300);
 });
 
$( ".choose_nav_landing" ).click(function(event) {
 $("#accordation").toggleClass('accordation-open');
 $("#accordation").toggleClass('accordation-close');
 });
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.choose-site-landing{
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
.choose-site-landing{
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 width: 100%;
}
}
.choose_nav_landing {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav_choose_lp{
 width: inherit !important;
}
.nav_choose_lp>.menu_choose_landing {
    width: 367px !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px){
.nav_choose_lp>.menu_choose_landing {
    width: 100% !important;
}
}
.choose_nav_landing > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #086EA1;
}
.choose_nav_landing > li:hover {
    background-color: #054c70;
}
.choose_nav_landing li.menu_choose_landing a {
    color: #ffffff;
    min-height: 58px;
}
.choose_nav_landing li a {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Nimbus Sans Reg";
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 17px 20px 17px 20px;
    line-height: 19px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto !important;
}
.choose-list {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.choose-list li {
    font-family: "Nimbus Sans Reg";
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    background-color: rgb(232,232,232,1.0) !important;
    background: #e8e8e8 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
.choose-list li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #086EA1 !important;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 21px 20px 21px 23px !important;
}
.choose-list li a:hover,.choose-list li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(216,216,216,1.0) !important;
    background: #d8d8d8 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    color: #054C70 !important;
}
.choose-list li a:active{
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: rgb(216,216,216,1.0) !important;
    color: #043954 !important;
    background: #d8d8d8 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
.choose-list li a:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: rgb(241,241,241,1.0) !important;
 background: #f1f1f1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
.choose-list li:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: rgb(241,241,241,1.0) !important;
 background: #f1f1f1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
/* .choose-list li:hover:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #d8d8d8 !important;
} */
.choose-site-mar {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: 1010;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px){
.choose_nav_landing li a {
    padding: 17px 18px 17px 18px;
}
.choose-list li {
    background-color: #033b57 !important;
}
.choose-list li a {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
        padding: 21px 18px 21px 18px !important;
}
.choose-list li a:hover,.choose-list li a:focus {
    background-color: #033b57 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
.choose-list li a:active{
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #033b57 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
.choose-list li a:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #054c70 !important;
}
.choose-list li:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #054c70 !important;
}
.choose-site-mar {
    position: unset;
}
}
.icon-accordation{
 padding-right: 15px;
}
.accordation-open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: 0.30s;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: opacity .30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .30s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .30s ease-in-out;
}
.accordation-close {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.30s;
  transition:  .30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:  .305s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:  .30s ease-in-out;
}
.site-icon-link{
 background-image: url(/content/dam/sunita/arrowRightInteractiveBlue.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
}
.site-text{
 word-break: break-word;
    margin-right: 30px; 
}
.choose-list li a:hover .site-icon-link,.choose-list li a:focus .site-icon-link{
 background-image: url(/content/dam/sunita/arrowRightDarkBlue.png);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px){
.site-icon-link{
 background-image: url(/content/dam/sunita/arrowRightWhite.png);
 right: 15px;
}
.site-text{
    margin-right: 20px; 
}
.choose-list li a:hover .site-icon-link,.choose-list li a:focus .site-icon-link{
 background-image: url(/content/dam/sunita/arrowRightWhite.png);
}
}
</style>
```

```html
<sly data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}"><h1>Edit Choose Site</h1></sly>
<sly data-sly-use.siteList="com.trp.wtc.sunita.pojo.ChooseSite"/>
<div class="choose-site-landing js-rem-ous">
 <ul class="choose_nav_landing nav_choose_lp">
  <li id="chooseSiteHolder" class="menu_choose_landing menu-login-branded " >
            <a class="nav_login_lp_top js-nix-click landing-state" href="#"><span class="icon-accordation"><img class="accordation-close" id="accordation" alt="accordation" src="/content/dam/sunita/twirlArrowWhite.png" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;"></span>${properties.title @context='html'}</a>
    <div class="choose-site-mar">
     <ul class="unbulleted choose-list js-remember" style="display: none;">
     <sly data-sly-list.listItem="${siteList.siteInfoList}">
     <li data-attr="${listItem.siteattr}"><a class="" href="${listItem.link @ extension='html'}" target="${listItem.newWindow == 'true'?'_blank':''}"><span class="site-text">${listItem.urltxt @context='html'}</span><span class="site-icon-link"></span></a></li>
     </sly>
   </ul>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I have a dropdown menu in my carousel, but it's appearing behind the carousel as shown here:

[enter image description here][1]

I have set z index in every place, but it did nothing.

I want the dropdown to appear outside the carousel, as shown here:

I have set z index in every place, but it did nothing.

I want the dropdown to appear outside the carousel, as shown here

Comment: Did you forget to include your snippet?

Comment: We cant do anything without the code or a link to the site.

Comment: Dear All, Sorry , I forget to attache my code snippet. I have just attached my code snippet in the down..But it is not the answer.

Comment: I attached your code as part of your question. please dont attach your code in the form of an answer next time. :)

Comment: Sure I will take care..As I am new to this forum , so faced some issue. From next time I will make sure , I will attache my code in question.